# Jenkins can't load configuration or start jobs after update from 2.207 to 2.214

Tags: jenkins, configuration

I updated Jenkins today and now when opening the setup I get the following error message when trying to open the configuration page:

```
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/Users/Jenkins/Home/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.214.jar!/hudson/model/UpdateCenter/CoreUpdateMonitor/message.jelly:53:20: <j:otherwise> can't parse argument number: changelog.url
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:726)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:281)
```

followed by another 200+ lines of stack trace **not** mentioning the the filename containing the `changelog.url` setting mentioned.

Where is `changelog.url` stored so I can fix it?

or alternatively: is there a way to get more informations on the problem?

## Update 1:

Found the [message.jelly](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/hudson/model/UpdateCenter/CoreUpdateMonitor/message.jelly) file which at line 53 contains:

```
  <j:otherwise>
    <j:set var="changelog_url" value="${app.CHANGELOG_URL}"/>
    ${%NewVersionAvailable(ucData.core.version,ucData.core.url,changelog_url)}
    <j:if test="${ucData.canUpgrade()}">
    <form method="post" action="${rootURL}/updateCenter/upgrade">
      <f:submit value="${%Or Upgrade Automatically}"/>
    </form>
    </j:if>
  </j:otherwise>
```

Does anybody known where `rootURL` points too?

## Update 2:

`rootURL` is the URL of my own Jenkins. So the Jenkins instance is currently sending invalid JSON to itself.

## Update 3:

After fixing the problem (see answers) it returned after a few day. Seems that the answers are only a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution on my system:

- Restart Jenkins manually to temporarily get rid of the error messages and stack traces.
- Restore previous Jenkins version and choose to restart Jenkins (ignore error messages appearing again).
- Update Jenkins to 2.217 (or newer?).

Now Jenkins should work again (at least it does here).

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't able to find out what the problem was a deinstall and reinstall of version **2.215** fixed problem.

Since `brew` installed a new version I can't tell if the deinstall (and with it cleaning up the installed files) or the new version actually did fix the installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation where you cannot perform operations on the jenkins host, but you have automatic upgrades enabled, you can resolve this situation by entering the following URL in your browser:

```
http(s)://path.to.jenkins/updateCenter/upgrade
```

When asked to resend using POST, just go on with that. This will trigger the upgrade to 2.217 which solves this issue. After than you just need to restart jenkins from the admin page.

Comment: Doesn't work for me because  `Jenkins upgrade not supported in this running mode` — I guess it's the `brew` installation.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if automatic upgrades are available, which is not the case of every installation (mostly when Jenkins does not own have the rights to overwrite itself).